# SBT 1.1.1 not using credentials for Nexus proxy

Tags: sbt, nexus

We moved to a new authenticated Nexus to act as a proxy to get dependencies.
I've tried to to give SBT (1.1.1) the credentials it needs, in multiple ways, but I always endup getting :

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager @ nexus3.company.com]
[debug] CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=https://nexus3.company.com/repository/maven2-proxy-all/org/scala-sbt/actions_2.12/1.1.1/actions_2.12-1.1.1.pom
```

It's repeated for a lot of dependencies.

I've created a .credentials file in my project as follow:

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 
host=nexus3.company.com
user=xxxxx
password=xxxxx
```

Here's what I've tried, based on inputs I got from other threads on the internet:

- Adding the path to this credentials file in the command : -Dsbt.boot.credentials=.credentials
- Adding the path to this credentials file to an environment variable : $SBT_CREDENTIALS = PATH
- Adding the following line in the build.sbt : credentials += Credentials(new File(".credentials"))
- Adding the following line in the build.sbt : credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "nexus3.company.com", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx")
- Checking what's going on with a proxy : my requests don't seem to have any authorization header and all come back as HTTP 401

And yet, when I access the URL mentioned from the same machine, with the credentials in the file, there is no issue at all.

I'm running out of ideas here :(

Answer (score 0):

After more attempts, adding :

~/.sbt/1.0/credentials.sbt
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "nexus3.company.com", USER, PWD)

AND

The SBT_CREDENTIALS variable mentioned above,

Seems to do the job.
I also updated the image we use for our pipelines, not sure if it helped.